# Disk Utility in 12.04 LTS will not let me check the file system partition for errors 

Tags: filesystem, fsck, disk-utility

I want to check my partition for errors using Disk utility.

When I press the "Check Filesystem" button, it says that an error occurred ... device is busy. How can I ignore that error and carry on with the check?

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device/partition may be mounted or being used by some process. Also, please don't try to run a check on a mounted file-system; can result in severe data loss.

I'd suggest booting from a Live CD/USB (ensure that your drives are not mounted) and then trying to run ``fsck".

Answer (score 1):

You can also run `fsck` on your (root) partition file system by booting in recovery mode.

Select the entry for `fsck` in the recovery mode menu (example below) and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image: recovery mode menu showing entry for 'fsck']